# Using Custom Struct inside of Class Definition

Tags: c++, class, struct

This is a relatively simple question, but the specifics are confusing me.

I have a basic struct as follows:

```
struct player {
    string name;
    int rating;
 };
```

and a class 'team' which would make use of this struct. With this in mind, where is the correct placement of the 'player' struct- inside the public/private fields of the team or in a separate file? Also, would there be anything different that I'd need to do in order to create an instance of it? Thanks.

Comment: I'm wondering if `struct player{ int rating; string name; };` is better alignment-wise...

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall The only difference would be where padding was inserted.  There is an argument for putting the smaller elements of a `struct` at the end, but it will never change anything with less than three elements, and would argue for the original layout.  And even when it would change something, the difference is usually negligible, and can be ignored.

Comment: @James, thanks, that was bugging me for a long time :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the how you use team/player struct. If you player is used by other part of the application, you should put player independent, that's the most cases do.

```
struct Player {
  int rating;
  std::string name;
};

class Team
{

private:
  std::vector<Player> players_;  // here you have a bunch of players
};
```

if your `Player` is totally internally used by `Team` and no one is using it, you can put it inside `Team` struct/class to narrow down its name scope.

```
 class Team
 {
 private:
   struct Player{
      int rating;
      std::string name;
   };

 private:
  std::vector<Player> players_;  // here you have a bunch of players
 };
```

Comment: quick sub-question:
what are the major differences (if they exist) in usage between the two examples? I use the player struct to describe data read in from a file (which would later be added as part of the 'team' class)- it is used independently, but always in the context of the team...

Comment: in first sample, other class can initialize Player objects and use them but in second sample, Player is in private scope of Team, no any other classes can instantiate Player objects.

Answer (score 3):

You have to ask yourself a question. Is the struct `player` meaningless unless in conjunction with class `team`? If so, it should probably be defined inside `team`; otherwise, it should be defined independently.

That is: if someone can conceivably want to use a `player` object that has not been directly retrieved from a `team`, you should make `player` an independent struct. Since we don't know the general structure or idea behind your program, we cannot give you a direct answer.

Answer (score 0):

simply define the struct before the class.
that should do the trick...

Answer (score 0):

I think a **team is a collection of players**, so it is convinient to use some container for managing the team.
 A lot of efficient containers can be found in **STL**, it is up to you to choose one which suits you needs best.
Also to mention, in order to group staff related to the same task you can use **namespace**.

Comment: I think both are entity objects, with their own identities, so they probably should be uncopyable, and the containment should be by pointers.

Comment: I agree, pointers can provide polymorphism, in case if the programmer decides to use inheritance and virtual functions.

Answer (score 0):

The key is whether it ia possible to use `Player` without using `Team`.  If so, it should be a separate class, and not nested.  In well designed conventional (OO) software, most nested classes are used exclusively inside the outer class, and are private.  Or they are proxies, used for return values from functions of the outer class, but never declared by clients of the outer classes.

It may also be deemed advisable to make other "views" of the class member classes; e.g. iterators into a container.  Whether iterators should be members, or free classes, is more of a style issue than anything else (but you should be consistent); it mainly affects the name (`ContainerIterator` vs. `Container::Iterator`).

Finally, templates introduce another dimension: given a template on a type `T`, it's easy, within this template, to reference members, including member types, of `T`; it's impossible to find "unrelated" types.  In other words, if you instantiate the template with `T == Container`, `Container::Iterator` is readily available as `typename T:Iterator`, but you have no way of finding `ContainerIterator`.

Given the names of your classes, I suspect very strongly that they should be independent, with `Team` having a `1-n` containment relationship to `Player`.  (I also suspect that both are entity objects, and should be made uncopyable and unassignable.  But that's another issue.)